# Linkedin API /company-statistics returns 500 Internal service error

Tags: linkedin-api

I am facing an issue with the LinkedIn API `/company-statistics`.

Using the Apigee console, I launched  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/company-statistics?format=json and got an `INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR 500`.

As you can see from the URL, I was using the LinkedIn Test Company 2414183 as suggested in the developer API guide.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. :(

Comment: @LinkedIn Almost a week passed without any answer. Please review this issue asap!

Comment: Hi folks, we're aware of this issue and currently looking to get a fix rolled out into production. We'll update this thread once it's been fixed. Thanks for your patience

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329048/internal-service-error-on-linkedin-rest-api

Comment: It seems to be working again now.

Comment: the issue is still present!! now please advise as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be related to the "test" company with id "2414183".

I had the same issue but when i used the same command with my company ID, I received a well formed JSON in response with all statistics.