# Internal service error on linkedin rest api

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I'm working on an app that uses LinkedIn api.

Since about two days I can't get any response from the endpoint "company-statistics".

To be more specific, I'm calling

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/company-statistics?format=json
```

And all I can get is an "internal service error", a sort of 500.

I tried the same api call in apigee console, with a brand new user account and requesting metrics from the testing company, provided by LinkedIn.

Nothing changed.

This is the response I'm getting since the issue appeared.

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "PTQ3EFE2DV",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1459414081903
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is still completely borked. @LinkedIn, why do you have to keep messing up your API? Sort it out.

Comment: We have the same problem. Can't find the cause or a workaround. This is a mess.

Comment: we started hitting this issue as well starting on March 26th. since then it has been failing consistently.

Comment: Yep, many clients are complaining about this. Did that department all quit?

Comment: @Jon Seems like they are finally addressing the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328622/linkedin-api-company-statistics-returns-500-internal-service-error

Comment: Seems to be working again now.

Comment: Hi, since yesterday, I have many "Internal Service Error" as response. I handle many linkedin accounts and the issue exists with the majority of this accounts. DO you think is related to a Linkedin update?

Comment: @Yhon A Yes, it is totally plausible.