# linkedin API company stats internal server error

Tags: linkedin-api

I recieved an error from  Linkedin API /company-statistics.

I was using apigee console, launching this API https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/company-statistics?format=json. and I get the following response:

{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "3D4B9V007S",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1464778594404
}

Plesa advise as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328622/linkedin-api-company-statistics-returns-500-internal-service-error/40629691#40629691).

> This error seems to be related to the "test" company with id
>   "2414183".
>
> I had the same issue but when i used the same command with my company
>   ID, I received a well formed JSON in response with all statistics.